# How do I use the shell function (Windows OS) in R to write data to a SQLite3 database?

Tags: r, shell, sqlite

I have a lengthy bit of code that basically loops through a series of functions for numerous sites. The output data for each site is appended and saved to a .sql file within the loop.

Once the loop is done, I want to insert the data from the .sql file into a pre-constructed sqlite database.

On Linux my working code looks like this:

```
settings <- c("PRAGMA cache_size = 400000;","PRAGMA synchronous =   1;","PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE;","PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;","PRAGMA auto_vacuum = NONE;")
command1 <- paste(paste(settings,collapse="\n"),"BEGIN;",paste(".read ",   (theFile.sql)),sep=""),"COMMIT;",sep="\n")
command2 <- paste(" | sqlite3 ", shQuote(name.OutputDB))

sqlCommand1 <- paste("echo ",shQuote(command1),command2)
system(sqlCommand1)
```

On Windows I can get this to work, but I lose the PRAGMA settings I want:

```
simplecommand <- paste0('cat ', (normalizePath(theFile.sql)), " | sqlite3 ", normalizePath((name.OutputDB)))
shell(simplecommand)
```

I have tried these following options on Windows that don't work:

```
command1 <- paste(paste(settings,collapse="\n"),"BEGIN;",paste(".read ",   (theFile.sql)),sep=""),"COMMIT;",sep="\n")
command3 <- paste("sqlite3\n.open", name.OutputDB)
command4 <- command4 <- paste0(".open ", name.OutputDB)


sqlCommand2 <- paste("echo ",shQuote(paste(command3,command1,sep="\n")))
shell(sqlCommand2)#Does echo work on Windows? Returns '"sqlite3'

sqlCommand3 <- shQuote(paste(command3,command1,sep="\n"))
shell(sqlCommand3)#Only seems to run the first line of code and open the database

sqlCommand4 <- shQuote(paste(command4,command1,sep="\n"))
shell(sqlCommand4,shell='c:/SQLIte/sqlite3.exe') # No error message, but no results written
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? Am I able to write multiple lines of SQL code using the shell command?

Thank you.

Comment: Why go the commandline route as R can connect directly to SQLite using [RSQLite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html) just as R can with any other major RDMS (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL, even MS Access) and run DDL and DML SQL statements?

Comment: I second @Parfait's suggestion to use `RSQLite`, but assuming something else is driving you away from that, can you write all of your commands (pragma settings, `BEGIN;`, `.read otherfile.sql`, `COMMIT;`) to a single text file and just issue something like `shell("sqlite3 database.sqlite3 < combinedcommands.txt")`?